# How to check which words of text appear in database and their frequency

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

I have a long text and a database table that acts as a dictionary, with the columns term, entity_type and main_name.

I would like to compare the words from my text to the term column and recover the terms that appear in the text, their frequency, their entity_type and their main_name.

I could do this looping through every word of the text, but it would be too long. Is there any way to optimize this process?

Comment: Look at `regexp_split_to_table()`  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#:~:text=%7Bhello%2Cworld%7D-,regexp_split_to_table,-(%20string%20text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First as Mike Organek suggests split your text to table with a query like this

```sql
select distinct upper(w) as word 
  from regexp_split_to_table(:your_text, '[^\w]+') w;
```

Then inner join it with the table and make your statistics

```sql
with words_in_text as
(
 select distinct upper(w) as word
   from regexp_split_to_table(:your_text, '[^\w]+') w
)
select tt.term, count(*) as frequency, tt.entity_type, tt.main_name
 from words_in_text wit
inner join the_table tt 
   on tt.term = wit.word
group by tt.term, tt.entity_type, tt.main_name;
```

Please note that if `term` is the primary key of `the_table` then you can group by `term` only.

[db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/a1evJkKxsDEKbiEgKnZsw7/0)